# How to get image from gallery which supports for API>=19 & API<19 both?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, image-gallery

Image is not importing, every time when I pic image from gallery in Android.

```html
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
    

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK
    && data != null) {
   imgUri = data.getData();
   // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
   String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imgUri, filePath, null,
     null, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor
     .getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

   bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

   cursor.close();
}
```

image is not importing every time ,some bmp sets nothing on imageview.

how to get **image from gallery** which **supports for API>=19 & API<19** both...

Answer (score 2):

This code'll solve the problem for **SDK < API11**, **SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19** and **SDK > 19**

**Declare it Globally**

```
public final int GALLERY_PHOTO = 2;
Bitmap newbitmap;
private Uri fileUri;
```

**Use this Method to Start Image chooser**

```
public void callGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            GALLERY_PHOTO);
}
```

**Use this condition in Default `@Overide onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`**

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY_PHOTO) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // SDK < API11
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {

                try {
                    realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(
                            Yourclassname.this,
                            data.getData());
                    setTextViews(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, data.getData()
                            .getPath(), realPath);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,
                                    null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    newbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);

                }
            }

            // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {

                try {
                    realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(
                            yourclassname.this,
                            data.getData());
                    setTextViews(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, data.getData()
                            .getPath(), realPath);
                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,
                                    null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    newbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);

                }
            }

            else {
                try {

                    realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(
                            yourclassname.this,
                            data.getData());

                    setTextViews(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, data.getData()
                            .getPath(), realPath);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,
                                    null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    newbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);

                }
            }

            // end

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canceled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                    "Oops!! Failed to pick Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

**Include this method in your class**

```
private void setTextViews(int sdk, String uriPath, String realPath) {

    Uri uriFromPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(realPath));

    fileUri = uriFromPath;

    try {
        newbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(fileUri));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    imageview.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);

    Log.d("Status", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT:" + sdk);
    Log.d("Status", "URI Path:" + fileUri);
    Log.d("Status", "Real Path: " + realPath);

}
```

**Create this Helper Methods in `RealPathUtil.class`**

```
public class RealPathUtil {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

     // Split at colon, use second item in the array
     String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

     String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };     

     // where id is equal to             
     String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

     Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                               column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
     }   

     cursor.close();

     return filePath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      String result = null;

      CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
              context, 
        contentUri, proj, null, null, null);        
      Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

      if(cursor != null){
       int column_index = 
         cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       result = cursor.getString(column_index);
      }

      return result;  
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
           String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
           Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
           int column_index
      = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }
}
```

Hope this will solve your Problem.

Comment: This code makes many invalid assumptions, not the least of which is that every `Uri` coming back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is one published by `MediaStore` and is accessible directly from the filesystem. This will break on hundreds of millions of Android devices where the user uses other apps (e.g., Google Drive, Dropbox) to choose the content, or where the content is stored in inaccessible locations (e.g., removable storage).