# More Elegant / Less Verbose Method For Sending Image Via Email On Android?

Tags: android, email

Currently I'm looking to send an image via e-mail intent and I've searched every stackoverflow answer I could find. Most of them were years old and did not support above API 19. I finally found an answer that was checked as correct for the current API, but it's a monster. Looking at it, I can't imagine that it's the best way to go about it. Most of the intent code previously was 20-50 lines at most. When you look at this methodology it's literally a huge mess, requires two additional classes, and really is not logic that I'm comfortable putting in to my project.

This solution I'm referring to can be found here:

[How to get image from gallery which supports for API>=19 & API<19 both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342678/how-to-get-image-from-gallery-which-supports-for-api-19-api19-both)

So my question is, can anyone provide a method for sending an image attachment from your phone's gallery with less (preferably much less) code?

Comment: That code will break on lots of devices. Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to get your `Uri`. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on that content. Copy it to a location that you control. Provide access to that location by some means (e.g., if you are using internal storage, use `FileProvider`). Use a `Uri` pointing to that location with your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. Some time later (e.g., tomorrow), delete the file.

Comment: Derp. This is literally my first Android Project. Do you think you could provide an example intent? If not, that's cool. I'll keep looking. I think I remember coming across a stackoverflow that seemed similar to that.

Comment: "This is literally my first Android Project" -- serving as a proxy between two other apps (whatever the user choose to get the content from, plus the email app) is not something I would recommend for one's first Android project. Or the second. But, no, I don't have sample code for it, for the simple reason that apps should not be trying to serve as proxies between two other apps. The user can send the email with the attachment from either the email app or the app with the content, most likely.

Comment: Hehe, I don't have much of a choice. It's a requirement. But thanks, anyway. I'll keep researching.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out to be really simple. At least, on the API I am debugging on (19). If anyone runs in to trouble on any other API's, please let me know as I'm trying to support as many versions of android as possible.

```
void SelectImage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent
            (Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("Result Code:", Integer.toString(resultCode));
        Log.d("Data Results:", data.toString());
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send E-mail"));
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) { Log.d("Exception:", e.toString()); e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```